# How to store functions in django models

Tags: python, django, models

edit: I completely rewrote the question as the original one didn't clearly explain my question

I want to run a function which is specific to each particular model instance.

Ideally I want something like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    data = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    perform_unique_action = models.FunctionField() #stores a function specific to this instance

x = MyModel(data='originalx', perform_unique_action=func_for_x)
x.perform_unique_action() #will do whatever is specified for instance x

y = MyModel(data='originaly', perform_unique_action=func_for_y)
y.perform_unique_action() #will do whatever is specified for instance y
```

However there is no datatype FunctionField. Normally this would be solvable with inheritance, and creating subclasses of MyModel, maybe like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    data = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    perform_unique_action = default_function

class MyModelX(MyModel):
    perform_unique_action = function_X

class MyModelY(MyModel):
    perform_unique_action = function_Y

x = MyModelX(data='originalx')
x.perform_unique_action() #will do whatever is specified for instance x

y = MyModelY(data='originaly')
y.perform_unique_action() #will do whatever is specified for instance y
```

Unfortunately, I don't think I can use inheritance because I am trying to access the function this way:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    data = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    perform_unique_action = default_function

class SecondModel(models.Model):
    other_data = models.IntegerField()
    mymodel = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)

secondmodel = SecondModel.objects.get(other_data=3)
secondmodel.mymodel.perform_unique_action()
```

The problem seems to be that I don't know what type the foreign key is going to be in SecondModel if I override the perform_unique_action in subclasses.

Can I access MyModel from SecondModel as a foreign key and still have a unique function for each instance of MyModel?

Comment: I can't really understand what you are trying to do. But to me it looks like you could achieve the same thing within your signals method without the whole "functions-in-the-model" approach. Can you try to describe your problem a bit more? Especially the last paragraph is hard to understand.

Comment: updated the last paragraph. If you could provide an example similar to the one above of how to achieve the same thing in the signal method without serializing functions that would be great.

Comment: Besides of you thinking that the methods you want to run have to be in the model, is there any other good reason for that? If not, why not run that method when the extension object is saved (via the signal)? You can get almost all data you might need from within a signals method since the actual instance is passed to the method.

Comment: I read your post again and had another idea. You want to "specialize" your `Extension` model with a function which differs from exteions to extension. Sounds like you should use inheritence in your models. Define a base model `Extension` and then define specialized versions of that model by creating another model that inherits the base model and overrides that method. Since you want to seperate concerns you should also split those individual extensions up in several Django apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me. I haven't tested it, but you should be able to create another class and override their methods and it'll work. Check the `class Meta` line, it'll treat it as an abstract class. Here's an example of my actual classes that I'm working on right now.

**EDIT:** Added VoteComment class and tested it. It works as expected!

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    VOTE_ENUM = (
        (VoteEnum.DOWN_VOTE, VoteEnum.toString(VoteEnum.DOWN_VOTE)),
        (VoteEnum.NONE, VoteEnum.toString(VoteEnum.NONE)),
        (VoteEnum.UP_VOTE, VoteEnum.toString(VoteEnum.UP_VOTE)),

    )
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, null=False, editable=False, blank=False)
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, null=False, editable=False)
    vote_type = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0, null=False, blank=False, choices=VOTE_ENUM)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def is_upvote(self):
        return self.vote_type > 0
    def is_downvote(self):
        return self.vote_type < 0

class VoteAnswer(Vote):
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, null=False, editable=False, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("voter", "answer"),) # to prevent user from voting on the same question/answer/comment again

    def __unicode__(self):
        vote_type = "UP" if vote_type > 0 else ("DOWN" if vote_type < 0 else "NONE")
        return u"{0}: [{1}] {2}".format(user.username, vote_type, answer.text[:32])

    def is_upvote(self):
        return "FOO! "+str(super(VoteAnswer, self).is_upvote())

class VoteComment(Vote):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, null=False, editable=False, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("voter", "comment"),) # to prevent user from voting on the same question/answer/comment again

    def __unicode__(self):
        vote_type = "UP" if vote_type > 0 else ("DOWN" if vote_type < 0 else "NONE")
        return u"{0}: [{1}] {2}".format(user.username, vote_type, comment.text[:32])

    def is_upvote(self):
        return "BAR!"
```

Comment: Would I be able to create VoteAnswer objects all with different is_upvote functions? If so can you please provide an example as I'm unsure how to achieve that. See my last code sample above with the foreignkey to see why I don't think subclasses are appropriate for my particular problem.

Comment: I just ran a quick test and added the VoteComment() class. It works as expected. VoteAnswer prints "FOO! False" and VoteComment prints "BAR!".

Comment: But every VoteAnswer object will print FOO and every VoteComment will print BAR. I'm looking to have five of the same object which all have different functions. So for your example, I'm looking to do this: vote_answer_obj.answer.some_func() where some_func will be different depending on the instance of answer referred to in vote_answer_obj. So far the examples only give unique functions for each class, not for each object. edit: I realise that I'm breaking OOP paradigms by assigning a function to a property rather than a method, but I can't see a way around it for my example.

Comment: Yeah, this is not how OOP works. All objects of a class will use same functions. However, I think you can probably make the use of function pointer. Maybe have a class to have a `func_ptr` member variable and then define `set_func_ptr(myFunc)` method to assign your custom function to the `func_ptr` variable. This could probably be your workaround. You'll have to define the custom functions somewhere outside of the class.

Comment: I was considering using marshal which is a way of converting a function to a serialized form, which could then be stored in the database... but it seemed the wrong way to do things and potentially prone to security flaws. Thanks a lot for helping me better understand my situation and potential solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with two ways of having a specific function defined for each object. One was using marshal to create bytecode which can be stored in the database (not a good way), and the other was by storing a reference to the function to be run, as suggested by Randall. Here is my solution using a stored reference:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    data = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    action_module = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    action_function = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class SecondModel(models.Model):
    other_data = models.IntegerField()
    mymodel = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)

secondmodel_obj = SecondModel.objects.get(other_data=3)
#The goal is to run a function specific to the instance
#of MyModel referred to in secondmodel_obj

module_name = secondmodel_obj.mymodel.action_module
func_name = secondmodel_obj.mymodel.action_function

module = __import__(module_name)
func = vars(module)[func_name]
func()
```

Thanks to everyone who replied, I couldn't have got to this answer if it weren't for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could achive some similar behavior overriding the save method. And providing special callbacks to your instances.

Something like:

```
def default_function(instance):
    #do something with the model instance

class ParentModel(model.Model):
    data = models.CharField()
    callback_function = default_function

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if hasattr(self, 'callback_function'):
            self.callback_function(self)
        super(ParentModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class ChildModel():
    different_data = models.CharField()
    callback_function = other_fun_specific_to_this_model

instance = ChildModel()
#Specific function to this particular instance
instance.callback_function = lambda inst: print inst.different_data
instance.save()
```

Comment: This looks like what I need. However, is the callback function stored in the database? eg when I save an instance, then the instance goes out of scope, then I fetch the instance from the db again later, does it retain the callback_function?

Comment: Ok I had a quick hack and I see why you have the child model. I tried it with just the parent plus a 'change_func' function so I could set the parent function. But then when the model is refetched from the db it resets to default_function. The child will prevent this. Thanks for the help with this. Still not exactly what I want, I'll try editing and rewording the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can write endpoints on your server and limit their access to just your self. Then store in each model instance corresponding url. For example:

views.py

```
def funx_x(request):
    pass

def func_y(request):
    pass
```

models.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    data = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    perform_unique_action = models.URLField()
```

and then:

```
x = MyModel(data='originalx', perform_unique_action='http://localhost/funx_x')
requests.post(x.perform_unique_action)
```

Answer (score -1):

i dont know whether i understand u correct or not. but you can check out this example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).

Example:

A string representing an attribute on the model. This behaves almost the same as the callable, but self in this context is the model instance. Here's a full model example:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birthday = models.DateField()

    def decade_born_in(self):
        return self.birthday.strftime('%Y')[:3] + "0's"
    decade_born_in.short_description = 'Birth decade'

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'decade_born_in')
```

Comment: This will run the same function - decade_born_in - for every Person. I want to run a different function for each different instance of Person.