# Link a function to a model entry

Tags: python, django, django-models

I was looking at the result of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120652/how-to-store-functions-in-django-models) on linking a specific method to a model entry, but not sure the solution used in the end is that elegant...

I want to have some sort of pointer to a specific method from a model entry in the database. This is my idea on how to do it but it seems abit clunky:

```
class Results(models.Model):
    result_ref = models.CharField(...)
    result_name = models.CharField(...)
    result_unit = models.CharField(...)

def result_1_method():
    return "My custom result for entry 1"

...

>>> results_map = {1: result_1_method, 2: result_2_method, ...}
>>> required_result = Results.objects.get(results_ref='XAY')
>>> required_result_method = results_map[required_result.id]
>>> result = required_result_method()
```

Is there a better or more commonly used solution? Like storing a method as part of the db entry for example? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use pure logic. Your way is actually the best way to do it. However, if your references are not ever going to change and are pre-defined, then you could just have a method that uses an if, else with the id.

```
if instance.id = 1:
    logic or method call here
else if instance.id = 2:
    different logic or method call here
...
```

But just realize that this means your cases/logic references are pre-defined this way and can never change. So if you want that dynamic references, your solution is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. Your example is good because it would allow me to keep all the code within the model class, but if I start haveing a lot of instances its going to get pretty big!

Comment: Yeah that's true. I guess it just depends on circumstances